# Wireless disabled after connecting ethernet cable

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

Im using Linux Mint 13. Wireless has always worked fine but stopped yesterday after I connected to the internet via an ethernet cable. After I disconect the cable I cannot connect to Wifi. In bottom right menu it just says "wireless" is disabled. I have tried hitting Fn F8 to no avail. I ran:

```
sudo rfkill list
```

gives me:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no

sudo rfkill unblock 0

sudo rfkill list
```

gives me

```
 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no


 sudo service networking start
```

results in:

```
networking stop/waiting
```

The contents of /etc/network/interfaces is

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? That wireless is disabled while you are connected via ethernet, or that, after you disconnect from ethernet, you were unable to reconnect via wireless?

Comment: After I disconnect from ethernet I am unable to connect to wireless. Usually in the bottom right menu it says "enable wireless" but now it just says "wireless is disabled"....

Comment: When this happens again, can you pls post the content of /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: suddenly it's starting working, after multiple reboots!